# File download stalling in Groovy/Java

Tags: java, download

I'm using FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile to download a variety of files (each in the 10MB-200MB range). Some of the files are located on a Chinese hosted CDN, so the internet connectivity to it is dubious at times. Using wget normally results in the file downloading fine - but it often shows longish periods of stalling where I expect FileUtils to break (I don't always get an error).

Is there a configuration for copyInputStreamToFile, or an alternative to it that handles stalls better? I'd really prefer this to calling out to a shelled 'wget'.

Alternatively, is there an accurate way to tell if a download has failed so I can delete the incomplete files and restart (without hashing the file and comparing it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a specialised library for downloading files. Google API Client has one for example:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-download

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/Test.jpg");

MediaHttpDownloader downloader = new MediaHttpDownloader(transport, httpRequestInitializer);
downloader.setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener());
downloader.download(requestUrl, out);
```

Search "google-api-client" in maven for latest version.